# Format a column as percentage in SSAS tabular model when the column is retrieved as % already

Tags: hive, ssas-tabular

I have the following metric retrieved from a HIVE database :

```
Success_Rate
0.1
1.09
5.00
-0.34
...
```

This column is already calculated in percentage from the source and when I try to format it in the SSAS Tabular as Percentage like below :

[image]

The output becomes like below :

```
Success_Rate
    10%
    109%
    500%
    -34%
    ...
```

Instead of :

```
Success_Rate
    0.1%
    1.09%
    5.00%
    -0.34%
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your hive database, you can either create another column where you multiply by 100
and then in the tabular model you can update the Data Format to Percentage and you will have the correct formatting.
Or, you can create a column with the same logic (multiplying by 100) in the tabular cube and apply the formatting.